# MySQL Query Efficiency Suggestion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Although this question is specific to MySQL, I wouldn't mind knowing if this answer applies to SQL engines in general.

Also, since this isn't a syntax query, I'm using psuedo-SQL for brevity/clarity.

Let's say C[1]..C[M] are a set of criteria (separated by AND or OR) and Q[1]..Q[N] are another set (separated by OR).  I want to use C[1]...C[M] to filter a table and from this filtered table, I want all the rows matching Q[1]...Q[N].

If I were to do:

```
SELECT ... FROM  ... WHERE (C[1]...C[M]) AND (Q[1]...Q[N])
```

Would this be automatically optimized so that C[1]...C[M] is found only once and each Q[i] is run against this cache'ed result?  If not, should I then split the query into two like so:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE C[1]...C[N]
SELECT ... FROM TEMP WHERE Q[1]...Q[N]
```

Comment: Sadly, this question is a bit too broad: the specifics of your query, schema and RDBMS will all influence the answer.  With current versions of MySQL, except for simple boolean simplifications and prioritisation of clauses that can use an index, I think that the optimiser will choose some indeterminate order for the lazy evaluation of remaining clauses.  I don't believe there is any way that one can influence this without going via another table (although one could use a materialised table from a subquery rather than a temporary table across multiple queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the job of the internal query optimizer to calculate the best order for compiling the joins according to filters.

For instance in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id AND table2.column = Y
        INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id2 = table2.id2  AND table3.column = Z
WHERE
    table1.column = X
```

Mysql (/oracle/sqlserver etc...) would *try* to compute beforehand each intermediary resultset to provide the best performances, and actually here the engine is doing a pretty good job.

However, everything relies on the statistics it actually has about the tables and the indexes you've setup in your architecture. These 2 points (apart from filling up the tables with datas...) are the only ones you can influence to help the optimizer to make good decisions by giving it the right and accurate information.

I hope it helped.

ps: have a look at this. This is about operators and order of precedence in queries compilation under oracle yet it is probably a good thing to know anyway:

http://ezinearticles.com/?Oracle-SQL---The-Importance-of-Order-of-Precedence&id=1597846

Comment: Got it, and checking out the link.  Thanks for all the responses.  It seems that -- long story short -- I should play it safe and create that intermediate table to ensure things are "cached" the way I want them.

Comment: I really, really don't think you should. What you should do is 1- build a DDL that matches your business and 2-refine it according to the queries you want to do. Queries should not match the model but the contrary.

Comment: Thank you.  I am sort of doing that.  I haven't structured my tables yet, but am working backwards from the queries I expect to do and trying (within the constraints of normalization) to structure my tables accordingly.  However, since I know little of how (My)SQL optimizes things, my "query optimization" is largely focused on making my queries easier to understand than efficient.